# How to graph a series defined function like $\sigma_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n$?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pstricks, loops, pgfmath

I want to graph, for example, this function: $\sigma_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n$.

Comment: I think you can only write the terms of the series in finite numbers.